# Excel not returning 2d spill from XLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup, spill-range

I think I can do this with words.

I have the following:-

```
=XLOOKUP($B6,$W6#,$AA6#:$AD6#,"")

B6 = A key
W6# = A dynamic array of keys
AA6#:AD6# = 4 pieces of data related to key.
```

Works just fine returning a 1 row and 4 column spill range to the current cell.

What I actually want is n rows and 4 column spill range.The list of keys  being held at B6#

I expected this to work:-

```
          
 =XLOOKUP($B6#,$W6#,$AA6#:$AD6#,"")
```

It doesn't. It only returns the first column, but does return all the rows.

By experimentation with VLOOKUP, INDEX and FILTER they exhibit the same behaviour.

I can produce the required output in other ways, but I thought I should be able to do it as above.

[image]

Comment: You say *"I can produce the required output in other ways"*. Could you share another way (I don't mean by using a LAMBDA e.g. `REDUCE` with `VSTACK`)?

Comment: `=INDEX(AA6#,XMATCH(B6#,W6#),{1,2,3,4})` would also work, just like `=CHOOSEROWS(AA6#,XMATCH(B6#,W6#)` and blanks within the array are returned as blanks by both. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZIHr.jpg

Comment: This covers it all: `=IFNA(INDEX(AA6#:AD6#,XMATCH(B6#,W6#),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(AA6#:AD6#))),"")`. `=CHOOSEROWS($AA6#:$AD6#,XMATCH($B6#,$W6#))` returns `#N/A`
for a single mismatch.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Gotcha. I thought you ment empty values in the returning spill range.

Comment: @VBasic2008 for my data I able to use VLOOKUP on each column and combine it with VSTACK

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Then I hope you like the improvement.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me more ideas. I am trying to add a picture to the question. Not every key has data.

Comment: I've looked at the screenshot and it has nothing to do with the posted references. Also, your question was closed. It is best to ask a new question with the new issues and we'll be glad to help. The issue here was about `XLOOKUP`. It can only return a single row or column when an array is supplied as the lookup value. Why? Maybe someone at Microsoft knows. They probably couldn't implement it. Surely they must have seen how cool it would be.

Comment: Try `=IFNA(INDEX(G3:H6,XMATCH(A3:A17,F3:F6),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(G3:H6))),"")` in `C3`.

Comment: Brilliant. I will deconstruct that to figure exactly what it's doing in what order. I think I understand why.